# Coloring axis/tick labels

Tags: matplotlib, colors, label, xticks, text-coloring

How would one color y-axis label and tick labels in red?

So for example the "y-label" and values 0 through 40, to be colored in red.
[image: sample_image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_ylabel("y-label")

for i in xrange(5):
    ax.plot(x, i * x, label='$y = %ix$' % i)

ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
  label = plt.ylabel("y-label")
  label.set_color("red")
```

similarly, you can obtain and modify the tick labels:

```
[i.set_color("red") for i in plt.gca().get_xticklabels()]
```

Comment: I would generally suggest a for loop in the second case, since assigning and returning values in a list comprehension is considered bad practice.

Comment: So what should I do if I only want one of the xticklabels to have a color. To let say, highlight one xticklabel.

Comment: It's considered poor pythonic programming to use a list-comprehension for a side-effect. This should be done in a for loop, not a comprehension. [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5753614/7758804). A comprehension is for building a list; if you're not building a list, then don't use a comprehension. See [Overusing list comprehensions and generator expressions in Python](https://treyhunner.com/2019/03/abusing-and-overusing-list-comprehensions-in-python/#:~:text=List%20comprehensions%20are%20for,don%E2%80%99t%20use%20a%20comprehension.)

Answer (score 28):

The xlabel can be colorized when setting it,

```
ax.set_xlabel("x-label", color="red")
```

For setting the ticklabels' color, one may either use `tick_params`, which sets the ticklabels' as well as the ticks' color

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')
```

[image]

Alternatively, `plt.setp` can be used to only set the ticklabels' color, without changing the ticks' color.

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), color="red")
```

[image]

*Note that for changing the properties on the y-axis, one can replace the x with a y in the above.*

Comment: I wonder why for `tick_params` it uses the keyword  `colors` and not `color` like the others? (Just spent 10 minutes debugging this because I used the wrong word)

Comment: Documentation of tick_params here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html (though seems incomplete ... font weight?)