# Issue with matplotlib accepting different color forms

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

So this is a simplified version, but as you can see I create a graph with matplotlib and display it. I display it with 'gray21' which has worked for Tkinter objects, but its not working here. The color 'white' is the only one I have found that works. How can I get a variety of colors? Can I use RGB or some form of exact color specification, because I have a color in mind (R:70 G:70 B:70). What forms of colors does .patch.set_facecolor() take?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from Tkinter import *


root=Tk()
root.geometry('1000x700')
root.configure(bg="gray21")
root.title("My Graph")


one_day_fig=plt.figure()

one_day_fig.patch.set_facecolor('gray21')
plt.plot([1,2,3], [2,4,6])
my_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(one_day_fig,master=root)
plot_widget = my_canvas.get_tk_widget()
plot_widget.place(x=50, y=50)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/users/colors.html

Comment: @Goyo so it said that RGB takes 3 numbers, so if my RGB value was 70, 70, 70, wouldn't I do one_day_fig.patch.set_facecolor(.7, .7, .7) ? This however didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you read the error message? Also what is said is "an RGB or RGBA tuple of float values".

Comment: @Goyo yes, it says: TypeError: set_facecolor() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)  This is odd because I gave 3 values, not 4. And what does RGB or RGBA tuple of floats mean?

Comment: @Goyo sorry autocorrect. Ok so what would my parameters be if my wanted color is R:70 G:70 B:70 ? Would it be one_day_fig.patch.set_facecolor([.7, .7, .7])? Because I have tried that

Comment: It's counting the figure as an implicit argument. You have to provide only one. A tuple would be `one_day_fig.patch.set_facecolor((.7, .7, .7))` but a list works for me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RGB values can be specified as 3-tuples of integers between 0 and 255 or as 3-tuples of floats between 0 and 1.

The tuple `(70,70,70)` would thus correspond to `(70/255., 70/255., 70/255.)`.

This can be used as a color specification to matplotlib.

```
figure.set_facecolor((70/255., 70/255., 70/255.))
```

Comment: Ah thank you! Would you happen to know how to change the font colors of my x and y axis?

Comment: This is not a chat here. If you have a question, ask a question. But make sure the question hasn't been asked already. As you can imagine you're not the first one that wants to change some color in the plot, so possibly [this is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165344/matplotlib-coloring-axis-tick-labels) you're after?!