# Matplotlib custom styles: different tick color and tick label color

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

This is a somewhat a follow up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165344/matplotlib-coloring-axis-tick-labels) question, where the author wants different tick and tick label colors. I want to have these settings saved as a Matplotlib style. But in Matplotlib styles, I can only set the tick color (see below for xtick settings), which changes tick and tick label color at the same time.

```
xtick.major.size     : 4      # major tick size in points
xtick.minor.size     : 4      # minor tick size in points
xtick.major.pad      : 6      # distance to major tick label in points
xtick.minor.pad      : 6      # distance to the minor tick label in points
xtick.color          : 555555      # color of the tick labels                   <---
xtick.labelsize      : medium # fontsize of the tick labels
xtick.direction : in # direction: in or out
```

In my company, we have grey ticks and black tick labels, how can I achieve this for all my plots?

thanks for your help
kuzco

Comment: It doesn't appear possible to do this using a saved style. You may have to change the tick label colour manually unfortunately

Comment: `xtick.color` sets the color for both, [tickmarkers](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/b01bdf44c420115c923e266fbcbd97aab14960a5/lib/matplotlib/axis.py#L134) and [ticklabels](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/b01bdf44c420115c923e266fbcbd97aab14960a5/lib/matplotlib/axis.py#L145).

Comment: @DavidG: oh, that is too bad, maybe I'll file a feature request.
@ImportanceOfBeingErnest: yup, that is correct. I want to set them seperately, though. I was looking for something like `xtick.labelcolor` and `xtick.tickcolor`.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue as you have.

I have submitted a bug report to Matplotlib (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/17659) and wrote a PR to address this issue (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/17661). So, starting from Matplotlib v3.4.0 (not released yet, but available on the master branch now), this is fixed.

Previously, `xtick.color` used to define the tick color and the label color.
The label color can now be set independently using
`xtick.labelcolor`. It defaults to "inherit" which will take the value
from `xtick.color`. The same holds for `ytick.[label]color`.
For instance, to set the ticks to light grey and the tick labels
to black, one can use the following code in a script:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelcolor'] = 'lightgrey'
mpl.rcParams['xtick.color'] = 'black'
mpl.rcParams['ytick.labelcolor'] = 'lightgrey'
mpl.rcParams['ytick.color'] = 'black'
```

Or by adding the following lines to the matplotlib rc file or a
matplotlib style file:

```
xtick.labelcolor : lightgrey
xtick.color      : black
ytick.labelcolor : lightgrey
ytick.color      : black
```

I hope this helps someone!